# Apache Kafka Streams Materializing KTables to a topic seems slow

Tags: stream, apache-kafka, reactive-programming

I'm using kafka stream and I'm trying to materialize a KTable into a topic.

It works but it seems to be done every 30 secs or so.

How/When does Kafka Stream decides to materialize the current state of a KTable into a topic ?

Is there any way to shorten this time and to make it more "real-time" ?

Here is the actual code I'm using

```
// Stream of random ints: (1,1) -> (6,6) -> (3,3)
// one record every 500ms
KStream<Integer, Integer> kStream = builder.stream(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.Integer(), RandomNumberProducer.TOPIC);

// grouping by key
KGroupedStream<Integer, Integer> byKey = kStream.groupByKey(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.Integer());

// same behaviour with or without the TimeWindow
KTable<Windowed<Integer>, Long> count = byKey.count(TimeWindows.of(1000L),"total");

// same behaviour with only count.to(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.Long(), RandomCountConsumer.TOPIC);
count.toStream().map((k,v) -> new KeyValue<>(k.key(), v)).to(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.Long(), RandomCountConsumer.TOPIC);
```

Comment: Could you be more clear on what you're trying to accomplish? Some code? Do you mean you're doing something like: ktable.to("topic_name")?

Comment: yes this is exactly what I'm doing

Comment: Ok, I understand your issue but unfortunately I have never tuned this specific case yet(I will actually need something similar to this soon as we're implementing a solution that requires this to be very fast / up to date) with that said I would start playing with the available configurations: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#configuration   Possibly first with the following: 
broker level: log.flush.* ones, offsets.commit.timeout.ms, 
producer timeouts.
topic level:  flush.* ones
stream level: commit.* ones
If you find a solution please post it here, It will be useful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is controlled by commit.interval.ms, which defaults to 30s. More details here:
http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html

> The semantics of caching is that data is flushed to the state store and forwarded to the next downstream processor node whenever the earliest of commit.interval.ms or cache.max.bytes.buffering (cache pressure) hits.

and here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-63%3A+Unify+store+and+downstream+caching+in+streams

Comment: the documentation does not describe the effects of these settings on speed